# Performing crud operation on array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

```
const blogPostSchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  tags: [String]
});
```

How to edit delete works on the tags as I want to do crud operation on tags as I got documentation for it not getting understand thanks in advance and here is the url of that documentation
https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/array

As I want to know these schema work in mongodb through mongoose as I am struggling how things works

Answer (score 0):

if you want handle with array in mongoose  to update or delete , you just learn about operator in mongodb to query db. At here, if you want add element in tags you can use updateOne with operator like "$push". if delete you can use deleteOne with operator like "$pull"

Comment: Although it's is an array how does the edited and delete  function known  on which element we have to perform this operation

Comment: you must pass id of element